# How do I get Facebook Connect to alert me when people comment on my blog?

Tags: facebook

I'm using Facebook Connect's "Comments Box" (http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Comments_Box) to handle comments on my blog. However, there doesn't appear to be an easy way to find out when people comment - ideally I'd like to receive an email whenever it happens, but I'd settle for an RSS feed or similar.

Is there an easy way to set this up?

Officially as an admin you can enable "notifications" but these are just the passive things that show up when you log on to Facebook itself - I rarely do this, and anyway it doesn't seem to work for anonymous comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hook up the onComment event to ping you.  Take a look at the bottom of the http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Comments_Box page where they specify the `FB.CommentClient.add_onComment` callback.

Depending on your blog api, you could have the onComment callback make an ajax call to your blog, so then the blog server emails you.  We'd need more details to help you there.

Comment: Yeah, figured something like this would work. Don't you think it's a bit crazy that I have to write my own code to make this work, though?

Answer (score 1):

You can now add yourself as a Moderator, and then you'll get notifications via Facebook's own notifications system.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

Here's a detailed description of how to set it up if you have your own PHP-capable server. It's about adding Facebook comments to Tumblr, but I think the email notification part will work equally well with non-Tumblr blogs.

http://gallery.lifewithboys.com/tumblr/_article/add_facebook/index.html

//Lars